# Does this type definition handle empty lists?

Tags: list, haskell

I am answering [question seven](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10) of Haskell's 99 questions. However, I have come to the point where they define the type

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
```

and it, from my understanding, will not handle empty lists (ie. `[]`).

But in their example tests they show

```
*Main> flatten (List [])
[]
```

Does this type cover empty lists? If so, why?

If it does not, and is a mistake of the websites, how would one write a nested list type that handles empty lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The datatype `NestedList a` contains either elements of type `Elem a`, or elements of type `List [NestedList a]`.

The first of these, you already seem to understand. The second one, though, has as its argument a list (the normal sort) of `NestedList a`'s. This can be any list, including `[]`. Thus, `List []` is a valid `NestedList`, as would be `List[Elem 5]`, or `List [Elem 5, List [Elem 3, Elem 2] ]`.

Comment: Ah, thank you - I assumed that because something filled the `List` declaration it meant it was one or more... which doesn't make sense as I write this, since they are just types. Thanks again.